# org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets

```
AutomationReport.java

public class AutomationReport {


    private AutoTestDao autoTestDao;
    private EventDao eventDao;
public void setAutoTestDao(AutoTestDao autoTestDao) {
        this.autoTestDao = autoTestDao;
    }

    public AutoTestDao getAutoTestDao() {
        return autoTestDao;
    }


    public void setEventDao(EventDao eventDao) {
        this.eventDao = eventDao;
    }

    public EventDao getEventDao() {
        return eventDao;
    }
}


AutoTestDao.java

public interface AutoTestDao extends EfmsDatabaseDao {

/*******************************************************
       Need to implement these methods from EfmsDatabaseDao

    public Object getPrimaryKey(Object bean);
    public Object insert(Object bean);
    public Object insert(Object bean, boolean generatePK);
    public Object update(Object bean);
    public Object update(Object bean, boolean modifiedOnly);
    public int delete(Object bean);
    public Object findByPrimaryKey(Object key);

    *******************************************************/

   //Methods

}


AutoTestDaoImpl.java

public class AutoTestDaoImpl extends AutoTestDaoBaseImpl implements AutoTestDao { 
           private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public AutoTestDaoImpl(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds);
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    public AutoTestDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate template) {
        super(template);
    }

     //Methods Implemantation

}
```

```
<import resource="classpath:tp_dao.xml"/> 
<import resource="classpath:tp_etl_db.xml"/>

 <!--   This for local testing  -->

<!--bean id="DataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</value></property> 
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@floradbdv1.ims.att.com:1521:efmsdv</value></property> 
    <property name="username"><value>efms</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>efms8135</value></property>
</bean> -->

<bean id="transcationTemplate" 
      class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">   
      <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <constructor-arg><ref bean="DataSource"/></constructor-arg>
      </bean>
 </constructor-arg>  
</bean>

<bean id="autoTestDao" class="efms.db.dao.impl.AutoTestDaoImpl">  
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="DataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="eventDao" class="efms.db.dao.impl.EventDaoImpl">  
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="DataSource"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="automationReport" class="efms.bizobj.AutomationReport">       
     <property name="autoTestDao"> <ref bean="autoTestDao"/></property>
     <property name="eventDao"> <ref bean="eventDao"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="psatMetricsHome" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="wotAutomationReport" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ctaAutomationReport" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="eadAutomationReport" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="ddAutomationReport" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="eventAutomationReport" 
      class="efms.controller.AutomationReportController">        
    <property name="automationReport"> <ref bean="automationReport"/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/PSATMetricsHome.html">
                <ref bean="psatMetricsHome" />
            </entry>

            <entry key="/WOTAutomationReport.html">
                <ref bean="wotAutomationReport" />
            </entry>

            <entry key="/CTAAutomationReport.html">
                <ref bean="ctaAutomationReport" />
            </entry>

            <entry key="/EADAutomationReport.html">
                <ref bean="eadAutomationReport" />
            </entry>

            <entry key="/DDAutomationReport.html">
                <ref bean="ddAutomationReport" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="/AutomationReport.html">
                <ref bean="eventAutomationReport" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
        /efms/jsp/
        .jsp

Everything was working fine until I upgraded to Spring 3 . While instantiating the page I am getting following error  . I am not able to track what could be the reason .

```
TrigTransactionDao,EfmsNewtonControlDao,DetermineServiceSr,UpdSvcActivationDetailsSp,EfmsDerivativePkg,GetSvcRequestByRuleSp,ServiceActivationAdminDao,ServiceActivationDetailDao,Service2speedCpeDao,ServiceActivationRuleDao,ServiceActivationRuleLogDao,DefEfmsTransMsProcDao,SvcActByUsrDao,ServiceActivationCandidateProcessingDao,SvcActivationTrackingDao,LoadSvcActivationTrackingDao,DqaAutoLogDao,DqaAutoProcDao,DqaChecklistDataDao,DqaChecklistNodalDao,DqaDvaConfigDao,TsnowMsgTrackerDao,CompleteEvent,CompleteWorklistItem,DeriveDqaServiceType,FqPurgeSp,SystemCompleteWorklistItem,PsatConfigActivityLogDao,PsatProjectExcludeDao,PsatProductDao,PsatOcoDao,PsatMcnExcludeDao,EfmsOmxEventInfoDao,GetNewWorklistPkg,EventHistoryDao,IssueUpdateDao,WfEventNotificationDao,EfmsOmxProcDao,EventJeop,propertyConfigurer,txManager,efmsDBTransaction,dbTransaction,DataSource,transcationTemplate,autoTestDao,eventDao,automationReport,psatMetricsHome,wotAutomationReport,ctaAutomationReport,eadAutomationReport,ddAutomationReport,eventAutomationReport,urlMapping,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
[10/30/14 13:06:48:569 EDT] 00000034 DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'automationReport' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/psatMetrics-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'efms.db.dao.impl.AutoTestDaoImpl' to required type 'efms.db.dao.AutoTestDao' for property 'autoTestDao'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [efms.db.dao.impl.AutoTestDaoImpl] to required type [efms.db.dao.AutoTestDao] for property 'autoTestDao': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:739)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Comment: `Failed to convert property value of type 'efms.db.dao.impl.AutoTestDaoImpl' to required type 'efms.db.dao.AutoTestDao' for property 'autoTestDao'`. This seems like the AutoTestDaoImpl doesn't actually implement AutoTestDao ... but I don't see how upgrade to Spring 3 could have changed anything about it if it was working before.

Comment: AutoTestDaoImpl is implementing AutoTestDao correctly , That's why I am not getting the root cause .

Comment: Could you show AutoTestDaoImpl and AutoTestDao ? And is there any AOP or transactional proxy anywhere ?

Comment: I have shown AutoTestDaoImpl and AutoTestDao above ... No we did not use AOP/transactional proxy